# How to store data from an Edit Text field, into an arraylist to be used for PSO algorithm test

Tags: java, android, algorithm, arraylist, particle-swarm

I am currently working on the Particle Swarm Optimization algorithm (PSO).

I have built a user interface on Android Studio that will be used for users to input their own test case scenarios to test this algorithm. This is the best way

I can explain it, the user will enter a name of a service, input the battery cost of the service for WLAN and for DATA, and the utility (priority) cost for the service between 0-100. The user will then enter the number of particles to test, the maximum number of iterations (normally 1000) and the predicted solution (normally 160 but will change this later).

When the "RUN PSO" button is clicked, the algorithm will test what the user inputted, and give a best global solution based on the runtime configuration, please bare in mind this isn't actually testing actual services/applications or resources, its using variables to represent those and then testing the variables.

I want to know how I can store the user costs for DATA, WLAN and Utility in arraylist. Please help me lol, if you need more information then do let me know.

I have attached an image of what the UI looks like so far, its quite basic.

[image]

Comment: Please add the code where you declare the editText (activity / fragment)

Comment: Hi @JonathanAste, that is pretty much my problem. I don't know where to start with it. If a user enters say a name of a service, "Facebook App", and then enters the cost for the DATA for that as 60, WLAN as 40, Utility as 60(pretty high priority), then he does another service, say "Twitter", 80 (DATA), 40(WLAN), 20(Utility), I want all the data costs stored into an arraylist, all the WLAN stored in an arraylist, etc etc.